# How to split points/Mark two answers as 'accepted'?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)

Hi. There is a discussion here between TOndrej and David Heffernan about who should get the points.

[I cannot use SHL (shift left) with int64 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015477/i-cannot-use-shl-shift-left-with-int64-variables)

For me both answers were good.
It looks like there is now way to make both participants happy.

I accepted the answer provided by TOndrej but David Heffernan does not really agree with it.
there is a way to mark both answers as 'accepted' - for me it will be totally ok.
Can a moderator mark both answers as accepted? If not, how should get the points?

Comment: The accepted answer is supposed to represent the one that was most helpful to **you**. Don't let David or anyone else try to bully you into accepting their answer instead of a different one. (That being said, of course, David's suggestions are usually top-notch. I highly recommend following his advice.)

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as "splitting points" (indeed, there's no way to award points on a question unless you've offered a Bounty, and they can't be split either, I believe) on stackoverflow. What you can do though is:

1. Up-vote each answer that helped you.
2. Mark as "Accepted" the answer that **helped you** the most. That's what an accepted answer is.

Also, there's no way for a moderator to "share" the accepted answer out between two, or more, answers.

Comment: That's the problem. Both answers were good (equal).

Comment: @Altar, in that case, if they both were truly equal, up-vote them both, write an answer *yourself* (crediting the two answers you've based it on) that contains the summation of the two answers and accept that.