# Which Answer to Accept: Better Solution or Answer to Actual Question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)

I received two answers to a question I asked. One solution suggested I do things in a completely different manner than I have been. Another acknowledged that the first solution was correct but went on to explain how to do what I was asking.

Should I accept the first answer because it provides the better way of doing things or should I accept the second one because it answers the precise question that was asked?

Answer (score 5):

Accept which ever answer helped you the most.

This could be either - that's for you to know and no one else can tell you otherwise.

You could also award a bounty to the other answer as an extra "thank you".

I assume that you've voted both answers up of course.