# what if there are 2 correct answers to my question

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)

I have posted a question and got different answers for the problem. But 2 of that answers provide accurate solution to the problem.

Now the issue is that, the 2 answers follow different approach for solving the problem and both the approaches are working perfectly. Now how should I award both the answers.

Answer (score 1):

First up-vote both answers if both are appropriate. Then you can accept any of the answers which is more appropriate to you. If approach of both answers are different, then accept answer whose approach do you follow. Additionally if answers are same then you should accept older one.

Note: Accepting an answer totally depends on OP. No one can force OP to accept their answer.