# Allow more than one accepted answer, if answers refer to different (sub-) questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

First of all, I do **not** think this is a duplicate of [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers). This question was about several answers that referred to the same question.

---

If I ask several questions or a question containing different parts, what should I do if different answers refer to different questions?

Consider a question about a math task that consists of two subtasks. IMHO there is no sense in creating two different posts for each subtask, if they are directly related. So what do I do if person A answers the first, and person B answers the second subtask in a separate question?

Of course I could (and should) upvote both of them, but I really think that awarding only one answer by *accepting* it isn't fair to the people who spent their time trying to help me.

This is why I would vote for a new feature that allows accepting more than one answer, if the provided answers are equitable.

Comment: Don't ask broad questions containing several parts.

Comment: [How to deal with different answers that would be a very great answer combined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280414/839601)

Comment: If you want to accept multiple answers, answering different parts, maybe you should ask multiple questions?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to accept multiple answers in case if you have multiple questions in one question. That's *not really good* and if I post a question, I care to ask only "one in one". But:

> Consider a question about a math task that consists of two subtasks. IMHO there is no sense in creating two different posts for each subtask, if they are directly related.

Yes, this happens. As I said, I would avoid it, but if you ask such a question anyway and you feel that those parts can't be split, the best answer is the answer which answers **all of the aspects you menioned**.

Other answers, which would only partly answer your question, aren't complete answers. Therefore there is no reason to accept it (unless you really want to do it: it's your decision after all). The accepted answer is most often **the answer which completely solved the problem**, this is why only one accepted answer is allowed.