# Who to up-vote - Integrated two answers to get to what I needed

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked a question over on StackOverflow and got two answers to my question. The one answered my question in the most technical sense, but an integration of the two answers received is what I used in my actual code, since that actually delivers the result I was looking for.

I couldn't have done it without the two answers I received, but who do I give credit now? Which one should I mark as "correct"? Or should I answer my own question, mark it as correct, and just up-vote the other two? I just want to be fair to the people that helped me and give them the credit they deserve, I couldn't do it without them.

This question is different to the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers) because without the one answer, the other doesn't entirely do what I want it to do, and vice versa.

Here is my question if you're interested: [Onsen-ui combining carousel with range input & action listeners/methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203275/onsen-ui-combining-carousel-with-range-input-action-listeners-methods/34215714#34215714)

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe, reopened. IMO you should write your own answer, mark it Community Wiki, then accept it.

Comment: Thanks, did it. I hope it's okay, but I just added a line at the bottom giving credit to the two users that gave answers from which my solution was derived?

Comment: @random "This question is different to the one here because without the one answer, the other doesn't entirely do what I want it to do, and vice versa" - you missed this?

Comment: Sure, what you did is fine @Nut. Sorry your question here is closed again, out of my hands now

Comment: @sha What part of "Sometimes, none of the answers completely answers my question. But, I will get a complete answer if I combine two of them together." did you miss?

Comment: @random the "I will get a complete answer" part.