# How to choose between several incomplete answers?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

If I asked a question (namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153270/how-to-get-a-reverse-mapping-in-numpy-in-o1)), and the solution I end up using is a combination of some of the answers, and another answer explains why it is correct,

How to choose the answer to accept?

Should I add an answer of my own that combines all the relevant insights and accept my own?

Please note this is a different question from [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396), because in my case the answers complete each other, and none of them is full by itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two factors that need to be taken into consideration:

- Which answer helped you most
- Which answer is most useful to future readers

If there is one answer that helped you most and you think that this answer will help others to find a solution to their problem, mark this answer as completed.

Otherwise answer with your own answer and mark it as accepted. If you think that you don't deserve the credit for this answer you can mark it as [*community wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). And don't forget to link to the other answers if they have provided good partial solutions that you used in your final answer.

Comment: But the other guys DO deserve the credit. No way to make it happen?

Comment: @Gulzar as I said you can mark your answer Community Wiki (no rep for anyone) or you could link to the other posts and thank them. You can also award a bounty to one of their answers if you especially like it.

Comment: @Gulzar: The other guys all get an upvote for their answer. That is credit too.